# Install a python package/module from github in local folder an use it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

### Issue

I would like to install with `pip3` a python module from github into a local folder named `local_lib/` and then use it in a script, **without any virtualenv**.

### Context

Here is my folder structure :

```
.
+-- local_lib/ // Folder where the package must be installed
+-- my_script.py
```

Here is the command line i use to install the `path.py` package from github into the `local_lib/` folder :

```
pip3 install --upgrade --target local_lib git+https://github.com/jaraco/path.py.git
```

Here is the content of the `local_lib/` folder after the command line :

```
.
+-- local_lib/ // Folder where the package must be installed
|   +-- __pycache__
|   +-- importlib_metadata-0.8.dist-info
|   +-- path.py-11.5.1.dev20+g3684c4d.dist-info
|   +-- zipp-0.3.3.dist-info
|   +-- importlib_metadata
+-- my_script.py
```

Here is the content of `my_script.py` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from local_lib.path import Path

if __name__ == '__main__'::
    print(Path('.') / 'generated_folder')
```

But when i execute the script with `python3 my_script.py`, i get the following error of import :

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "my_program.py", line 4, in module 
>   from local_lib.path import Path 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'local_lib.path'

Should i change the way i import the package into my_scipt.py **or** should i change the command line to install the package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell Python that it has to look in `local_lib` for modules. E.g. by adding it to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20path#sys.path) in your script (*before* importing from it) or by adding it to your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can just download the [path.py](https://github.com/jaraco/path.py/blob/master/path.py) file into your `local_lib` folder and your path.py use case should work. You don't need install it with `pip3`.

Should you want `path.py` to be available for scripts in any folder on the machine, using the same syntax, use the [solution from Roland Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54052435/6018688) or install it the generic way with `pip install path.py`.