# Two subsequent and dependent python pip install commands with custom target directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, gitlab-ci

Consider I have a GitLab CI/CD pipeline consisting of 2 stages: `stage A` and `stage B`.

each of these stages have one job associated with them:

`stage A -> job X`

`stage B -> job Y`

In job X of stage A, project python packages and dependencies are installed and are passed to job Y of stage B as artifacts. This was to give you a context about the problem.

To breakdown the issue into the main problem, in job X, I have two `pip install` commands as followings:

```
pip install git+ssh://git.example.com/repositoryx/projectx --target lib

pip install -r requirements.pip --target lib
```

The reason I'm using `--target` flag is that in GitLab CI, artifacts should be stored in project local directories. The problem is, the second `pip install` command depends on the first `pip install` output installed packages. It seems changing the target directory has not necessarily changed the directory that pip looks up for previously available packages. more specifically, second install does not find a package which is installed from the previous pip install in lib directory inside project.

Is there any other flag or generally solution to fix this issue and enable the 2nd `pip install` command to discover 1st `pip install` installed dependencies packages, considering the `target` flag necessary.

Note 1: if I remove the `target` argument from the commands, packages will be resolved by the second one and it will work, but I won't be able to take advantage of `artifacts` feature if GitLab CI, which is required in my case.

Note 2: In the end of the `job X`, I want to pass all the output packages of both commands as artifact. i.e, it's not the case that I use 1st command output only as an input to 2nd command.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use a virtual environment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54052435/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+target+import

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no, not really, just though it might be some kind of hack to pass the whole venv directory across jobs and there might be a better solution for it; custom target dir as an example. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @phd Does that indicate the `local_lib` for `pip` as well, or is only for python? Because in my case, I want to tell the 2nd pip command where to look for its already-installed and available packages from the previous pip command.

Comment: It seems like you are replicating what is basically a venv, thus my comment. You might be able to come up with something smaller that fits exactly what you need *and nothing more*, but a venv seems perfectly adequate to get the job done.

Comment: "*for pip as well, or is only for python?*" That's a strange question. `pip` is a Python script, it doesn't have any other search paths but only those that Python knows.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you use [caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) for dependencies?

Comment: @Dinac23 I've already used caching for its dependencies and it's been working as expected. Only the artifact part was the issue which has been resolved by passing venv as artifact. Anyway, thank you for the point.